# Comparison method violates its general contract - TimSort.mergeLo error

Tags: java

I saw various questions relates to the Timsort error here, and applied code change based on it. But none of them yields me result. Kindly help me in resolving my error.
Code:

```
    public int compare(Record record1, Record record2) {
    int indexOfRecord1=records.indexOf(record1);
    int indexOfRecord2=records.indexOf(record2);

    Integer sortIndexOfRecord1=indexToSortIndexMap.get(indexOfRecord1);
    Integer sortIndexOfRecord2=indexToSortIndexMap.get(indexOfRecord2);

    //Option 1: Throws same Timsort error:
    if(sortIndexOfRecord1!=null && sortIndexOfRecord2!=null){
        return sortIndexOfRecord1.compareTo(sortIndexOfRecord2);
    }else{
        return (sortIndexOfRecord1==null && sortIndexOfRecord2==null)?0:(sortIndexOfRecord1==null)?-1:1;
    }
   //Reframed the above logic like below. I got the same error
   //Option 2: Throws same Timsort error:
   /*
    if(sortIndexOfRecord1!=null && sortIndexOfRecord2!=null){
        if(sortIndexOfRecord1.intValue() == sortIndexOfRecord2.intValue())
            return 0;
        else if(sortIndexOfRecord1.intValue() < sortIndexOfRecord2.intValue())
            return -1;
        else if(sortIndexOfRecord1.intValue() > sortIndexOfRecord2.intValue())
            return 1;
    }else if(sortIndexOfRecord1==null && sortIndexOfRecord2==null){
        return 0;
    }else if(sortIndexOfRecord1==null && sortIndexOfRecord2!=null){
        return -1;
    }else if(sortIndexOfRecord1!=null && sortIndexOfRecord2==null){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
    */


    //Option 3: Throws same Timsort error:
    /*
    int index1 = -1;
    int index2 = -1;
    if(record1 != null && record2 != null){
        index1 = indexToSortIndexMap.get(indexOfRecord1)!=null?indexToSortIndexMap.get(indexOfRecord1):-1 ;
        index2 = indexToSortIndexMap.get(indexOfRecord2)!=null?indexToSortIndexMap.get(indexOfRecord2):-1 ;
    }else if(record1 != null && record2 == null){
        index1 = indexToSortIndexMap.get(indexOfRecord1)!=null?indexToSortIndexMap.get(indexOfRecord1):-1 ;
    }else if(record1 == null && record2 != null){
        index2 = indexToSortIndexMap.get(indexOfRecord2)!=null?indexToSortIndexMap.get(indexOfRecord2):-1 ;
    }else{
        index1 = -1;
        index2 = -1;
    }

    if (index1 > index2){
        return +1;
    }else if (index1 < index2){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
    */
```

All the above yields the below error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I tried wtth other options also. That too gives the same error. `code`

Comment: Huh.  That's...weird.  Is there any possibility either `records` or `indexToSortIndexMap` are being concurrently modified?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Nope.It wasn't concurrently modified. I have updated the code with all possible options tried.

Comment: Are you comparing some specific type, or `Object`?

Comment: I might try your original code, except I'd write `if (sortIndexOfRecord1 == null) sortIndexOfRecord1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE; if (sortIndexOfRecord2 == null) sortIndexOfRecord2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE; return sortIndexOfRecord1.compareTo(sortIndexOfRecord2);`

Comment: I'm slightly puzzled... what exactly is your ordering criteria?  (Preferably in plain English.)

Comment: @Makoto: its a java class... as i dont want to speciffy the class,  i mentioned it as Object in the code

Comment: That makes it a bit more confusing to me, since `Object` means something ***very specific***.  If you didn't want to specify the *actual* name, a valid name that isn't `Object` would do too.

Comment: @Makoto: Sorry for that... I have updated the code above

Comment: You are not sorting on the same `records` that you use to get the index, are you?!!! That will certainly mess up everything.

Comment: You have already said you are not concurrently modifying the List `records` or the Map `indexToSortIndexMap`, but are you also sure you are not modifying any of the `Record` objects themselves?  That might cause the results of `records.indexOf` to vary.

Answer (score 0):

The three options seems to be fine. However you can try to replace them with the standard comparator to be sure:

```
return Comparator.nullsFirst(Integer::compare)
                 .compare(sortIndexOfRecord1, sortIndexOfRecord2);
```

One possible answer is that you are actually sorting the `records` list that you use to get the index of the records. That's a really bad idea.

Comment: Or to get really fancy: `Comparator<Record> c1 = Comparator.comparing((Record r) -> indexToSortIndexMap.get(records.indexOf(r)));` then `return  Comparator.nullsFirst(c1).compare(record1, record2);`.  But the reported bug pretty much _must_ be due to concurrent modification of one or more of these objects.

Comment: I got your point on sorting the `records`. The issue is on concurrent modification. Let me remodify the code and try. Thanks.